# Spring Roo updating password field or not updating all fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I have an entity `User` that has `username`, `name`, etc ...

`User` also has a `password` property. And I disabled rendering of it in list/show forms, but in the update form, field is set to `type="password"`.

What bugs me is that you can't update user without re-entering password as no stars are there, and if you don't enter the password, `password` is set to `null` or `""`.

How can I bypass that?

There is also another issue. If I remove some fields from update form, all other fields are set to `null`.
What I want is to enable user to update some, but not all fields of some entitiy.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify.  Roo, by itself, can be very adaptable.  Are you using Spring MVC (Roo refers to it as Web MVC) scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an entity **Foo** with four fields *f1,f2, f3* and *f4*.

In **update.jspx** for this entity, I set the attribute **render="false"**  for field **f1**.

In the **FooController** update method, before the **foo** parameter object was updated, I fetched the old value from the db and stick it in the parameter **foo**, as shown below, because we do not want the end user to update this field.

```
    Foo fromDB=Foo.findFoo(foo.getId());
    foo.setF1(fromDB.getF1());
    foo.merge();
```

I am able to verify that old value for **f1** in Foo entity is not getting changed after the update operation was completed.

This could be one way to prevent users from updating some fields in an entity object and hope this approach works for you.

Cheers,